# Can the Model & Controller In ASP.NET MVC Be Useable For Other Views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, xaml, asp.net-mvc-4

Well I was thinking, is it possible to use the same ASP.NET MVC's Model & Controller for any sort of views such as command line , WPF or any other Xaml view layer ? because theoretically that should be possible .

I will be grateful if there's an actual implementation for this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure you won't be able to reuse any of your MVC architecture as you're wanting to, you'll have to adopt a slightly different pattern described below:

An alternative to MVC (Model View Controller) is  MVP (Model-View-Presenter). The model is essentially the same between the two and the role of the controller is also very similar. The controllers in MVP may get a little more responsibility depending upon your implementation. Within MVP, there are two implementation methods: Supervising Controller and Passive View. MVP is usually considered the standard architecture for WinForms clients and can be applied to WebForms as well. Here are some relevant links for more information:

- MSDN for MVP - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304760.aspx
- Supervising Controllers -
  http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/SupervisingPresenter.html
- Passive Views -
  http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PassiveScreen.html Jeremy Miller on
- MVP for ASP.NET -    http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2006/02/01/137457.aspx.
  You might also check out his Build Your Own CAB series. It teaches
  MVP as it applies to WinForms.
- Polymorphic Podcast screencast on Supervising Controller -  http://polymorphicpodcast.com/shows/mv-patterns/

Finally, if you want to pick up a book, Agile Principles, Patterns,
   and Practices in C# contains an excellent walkthrough for building a
   console-based payroll application. Once compeleted, they build to
   WinForms UI to show how their application architecture allowed them
   to add a new view with minimal fuss.

Comment: +1 for useful info, although the question about reuse of controller and model is left open somewhat

Comment: @soadyp Good shout, I've broken the bad news to him in the first paragraph :)

Comment: Essentially you should be able to reuse "models" in the various paradigms. Reusing controllers is less likely to be the case. Although not a big issue. Since controllers should be small and marshal calls to business logic.  So you can have support classes that have for instance UI rules and re-use those classes. But as Mattytommo suggests the paradigms are a little different and have different requirements. eg MVC controllers inherit from System.Web.Mvc.Controller.

Re-using views gets even more dubious.

Comment: @mattytommo Your Answer was exactly what i'm looking for I heard of MVP but I never look deep into it I guess it's time know more details about it as i'm willing to develop a windows 8 apps ,those links you provided will be my start point so thank you

Comment: @soadyp I guess you're right that the controller might be the only challenge to tweak , however i'm not sure that we can reuse the model layer without some modifications , because there's the interaction code between model and controller, but in any case using ASP.NET MVC for Xaml will be nonsense as far there's MVP to do the same task.